# EasyAdmin 3: customize select2 dropdown CSS and JS in AssociationField

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I am using Symfony 5 and EasyAdmin 3 in my project.

Here is an exemple of a CRUD Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Guide;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IdField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateTimeField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextEditorField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ArrayField;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Action;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Actions;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;

use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class GuideCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Guide::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        if (Crud::PAGE_DETAIL === $pageName) {
            $field = ArrayField::new('thematiques', 'Thématiques');
        } else {
            $field = AssociationField::new('thematiques', 'Thématiques');
        }

        return [
            IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm(),
            TextField::new('title', 'Titre'),
            TextEditorField::new('description', 'Description'),
            TextField::new('site_url', 'Url du Site'),
            TextField::new('site_url_button_text', 'Texte du Button'),
            TextField::new('slug', 'Slug')->hideOnIndex()->hideOnForm(),
            ImageField::new('image_url', 'Image')
                ->setBasePath('images/guides')
                ->setUploadDir('public/images/guides')
                ->setRequired(false),
            DateTimeField::new('created_at', 'Date Création')->onlyOnIndex(),
            DateTimeField::new('updated_at', 'Date Modification')->onlyOnIndex(),
            $field
        ];
    }

    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DETAIL)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_EDIT, Action::INDEX)
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_NEW, Action::INDEX);
    }
}
```

In the AssociationField, the CSS style and JS behaviour are provided by default by EasyAdmin.

However, I would like to modify the CSS to change the width of this form widget select dropdown and make it larger.

I would also like to modify the JS by default that closes the dropdown each time we select an item; because I would like to allow the dropdown to stay open with multiple choice to allow the user to select several items on the dropdown without the select menu closing every time we click on one item. I saw we could do this with event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault(); but I do not know how to apply a custom JS to a EasyAdmin particular form widget.

Does anyone has any idea how to customize CSS and JS of a multiple Association Field select2 dropdown in EasyAdmin 3 please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple method to customize your field, such as:

**Add class to your div (addCssClass)**

```
$field = AssociationField::new('thematiques', 'Thématiques')
    ->addCssClass('css-class');
```

And your select will turn into something like

```
<div class="field-association css-class form-group">
```

**Add css or js files**

```
$field = AssociationField::new('thematiques', 'Thématiques')
    ->addCssFiles(['file.css'])
    ->addJsFiles(['file.js']);
```

**Add webpack entries:**

```
$field = AssociationField::new('thematiques', 'Thématiques')
    ->addWebpackEncoreEntries(['custom-select']);
```

If you use addWebpackEncoreEntries, you have to add your entry to `webpack.config.js`, and use this entry to implement custom javascript and or css.

**Increase the size of your input:**

You could also use `->setColumns('col-12')` to increase the width of your input. For example:

```
$field = AssociationField::new('thematiques', 'Thématiques')
    ->setColumns('col-12');
```

---

You could easily use those classes to add custom css or javascript to increase the width of your association field.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks a lot for your answer. I have tried ->setColumns('col-12'); but I have got an error. And >addCssClass('col-12'); has not effect on the width of the select because there is a max-width of 350px I think. 

However I would like to override the CSS and JS files, but if I use ->addCssFiles(['file.css'])
->addJsFiles(['file.js']);

Where should I place these files on my project? Inside the bundle in vendor or in another place?

Comment: What is your error ? I used setColumns with an association field and it takes the whole row. And do you use webpack ?

Comment: I have been trying to override the template, I have created a folder in templates/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/custom/index.html.twig; bug Symfony is not recognizing my template. 

return $crud
            ->setEntityPermission('ROLE_EDITOR')
            ->overrideTemplate('crud/index', 'bundles/EasyAdminBundle/custom/index.html.twig');

Comment: That is the error :  Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\LoaderError: "Unable to find template "bundles/EasyAdminBundle/custom/index.html.twig" (looked into: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tips/templates, /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tips/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form)." at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tips/vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php line 227  

Any idea ?